# Wordpress Custom post type single page 404 error

Tags: rewrite-rules

I have a wordpress website where I am using custom post types. I have an error on all single custom post type pages of one of the custom post type called products registered as portfolio. If I refresh the permalinks, it gets fixed and in few mins the 404 returns again. When I checked the rewrite rules it shows liks this:

When it loads properly:

```
products/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$   index.php?portfolio=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]
```

when 404 error :

```
[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$    index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found same problem and I solved with extraordinary article of Brent Shepherd : [Advanced Taxonomy Queries with Pretty URLs](http://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/). This article contains a generic function to solved the problem and instructions for changes permalinks. 
It's very important don't forget enable module php: **mod_rewrite** in your server and modify the archive **/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf** with rules:
(for example in directory localhost, add)

```
 <Directory "/var/www/html">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

and restart your server: **sudo service apache2 restart**
This information explains in article [HOW TO ENABLE MOD_REWRITE IN UBUNTU](http://www.dev-metal.com/enable-mod_rewrite-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) .Then follow the instructions above all permalinks work perfectly!